# image view only shows background color in launch screen

Tags: ios, uiimageview, launch-screen

I'm having some problems with my app's launch screen storyboard.

When I run the app on an iPhone 5S, the image is displayed. **However, when I run the app on an iPhone 8, the background color of the UIImageView is shown.**

In the project settings, at **App Icons and Launch Images**, I am not using an image source (although trying do so doesn't seem to work either) and the **Launch Screen File** is set to LaunchScreen.

The View Controller has **Is Initial View Controller** checked and the file has **Use as Launch Screen** checked. The image set was brought in using **Import...** and is universal.

I've read through several of the solutions for black screen here, but switching the background color revealed that was where my black screen was coming from.

In the assets file, the image set has 1x @ 640x1136, 2x @ 1242x2208 & 3x @ 1125x2436. I experimented with other combinations, but this is the first set that let me see the actual image on the 5S. **I'm pretty sure the issue is not having the right configuration of dimensions in the image set file**, but can't be certain.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same thing. Working on the simulator but didn't work on the device (or any other possible option). It's just a bug.

Try these until it works:

1. Turn simulator/device off and then on again.
2. Hard clean simulator. Turn it off.
3. Clean/Hard Clean/Delete Derived data
4. Reboot Xcode

Hope one of these helps.

If not, please include the screenshots of working / non-working app screens.

Comment: have you tried uninstalling the app from the phone, hard clean project > build on the phone again?
also try simulator (even if it's slow.. cuz if there is no way to fix the issue you should take the worst case scenario and test slowly), just to know. to see maybe it's ios version issue or something else.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I had tried rebooting devices + Mac (simulator is too slow on my machine), but after a few hours taking a walk and receiving a phone call somehow did it. Must have been a caching issue.